# Count with WHERE condition

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following T-SQL query :

```
SELECT year, COUNT(*) FROM publis
WHERE publisher LIKE '%Springer%'
```

I made this query :

```
db.publis.aggregate([{"$group" : {_id:"$year", count:{$sum:1}}}])
```

How can I include the WHERE condition ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent of SQL `WHERE` is the [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) aggregation stage, so you would rewrite you query like so:

```
db.publis.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            publisher: /Springer/,
        },
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: '$year',
            count: { $sum: 1 },
        },
    },
]);
```

Comment: how can I sort by year ?

Comment: You should add a `$sort` stage after the `$group` stage.

Comment: use $sort by year after $match to better use index, and then $project only year and mute _id:0, year:1 for vertically slicing data, at last use $group for optimal performance upfront of millions of records.
1) $match 2) $sort 3)$project 4) $group